# Exclude rows with the same values in some columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the table like following:

```
id | col1 | col2 | col3   | col4
---+------+------+--------+-----------
 1 | abc  | 23   | data1  | otherdata1
 2 | def  | 41   | data2  | otherdata2
 3 | ghi  | 41   | data3  | otherdata3
 4 | jkl  | 58   | data4  | otherdata4
 5 | mno  | 23   | data1  | otherdata5
 6 | pqr  | 41   | data3  | otherdata6
 7 | stu  | 76   | data2  | otherdata7
```

How can I fast select rows where col2+col3 doesn't have duplicates? There is over 15 millions of rows in the table, so join may be not suitable.

Final result should look like this:

```
id | col1 | col2 | col3   | col4
---+------+------+--------+-----------
 2 | def  | 41   | data2  | otherdata2
 4 | jkl  | 58   | data4  | otherdata4
 7 | stu  | 76   | data2  | otherdata7
```

Comment: which postgresql version you are using ...if row_number() exists then you can do it easily.

Comment: Any index on col2/col3?

Comment: @anwaar_hell postgresql 9.4

Comment: @jarlh I can create any index if necessary

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, all of them is right, but in my case `NOT EXISTS` answer is much faster. Typical query with `COUNT` and `row_number()` takes about 30s, with `NOT EXISTS` < 100ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Window functions are definitely one possibility.  But, if you care about performance, it is also worth trying another approach and comparing the speed.

`NOT EXISTS` comes to mind:

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.col2 = t.col2 and t2.col3 = t.col3 and
                        t2.id <> t.id
                 );
```

This can take advantage of an index on `table(col2, col3)`.

Comment: Most of the time I have seen/used things like that. The single scan over the table was still faster than doing the `not exists` with a second "scan" - even if that second "scan" was only an index lookup. But it is worthwhile to check both solutions and verify this using the execution plan.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I only offered this as an option to be considered.  I think the distribution of the original data has a big impact on which performs better.

Comment: Index (id+col1+col2) does wonders. Typical query takes <100 ms. Big thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure how fast this will be, but this should work:

```
select id, col1, col2, col3, col4
from (
  select id, col1, col2, col3, col4, 
         count(*) over (partition by col2, col3) as cnt
  from the_table
) t
where cnt = 1
order by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this as well..

```
select * from 
(
select id,col1,col2,col3,col4
,row_number() over (partition by col2,col3 order by col2,col3 desc  ) as rnm
from
table
)  x where  rnm =1;
```

Comment: what do you think it will execute. It will give syntax error

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for pointing it out..but now it wil lcertianly run...:)